# How to customize dual axes barchart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, bar-chart

This is a follow-up question of this [R: How to build barplot with multiple bars and dual axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72487178/r-how-to-build-barplot-with-multiple-bars-and-dual-axis/72487572?noredirect=1#comment128054156_72487572)

I have df with 1 cat and 3 numerical variables. Now I would like to know how to order bar descending from the right to left by size of 'cost' (which is given by red line). After I want to specify the colour of every bars manually myself, but could not find the way. Also, is it possible to put this numbers (costs) in boxes?

```
df <- data.frame (model  = c("A", "B", "C","D","E","F"),
                  share = c(12,20,15,9,60,20),
                  sale = c(16,25,18,14,67,28),
                  cost = c(14,19,28,24,57,28))

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -model
  )



ggplot(df_long, aes(x = model, y= value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_point(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 2)+
  geom_text(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Define a vector with colors you like and then use `scale_fill_identity`:

```
colors <- c("black","blue","black","green","black","orange",
            "black","pink","black", "yellow", "black","green")

library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -model
  ) 


ggplot(df_long, aes(x = fct_reorder(model,desc(value)), y= value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=colors), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_identity()+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_point(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 2)+
  geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-1.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

**First answer:**
We could use `fct_reorder` from `forcats` package it is in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -model
  ) 


ggplot(df_long, aes(x = fct_reorder(model, desc(value)), y= value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 1)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_point(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 2)+
  geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: and how can I customize colours myself?

Comment: which colors do you want to customize by group or by model ?

Comment: yes. I want to specify colors of every bar myself

Comment: Please see my update!

Comment: boxes around numbers dissapeared

Comment: updated. change geom_text to geom_label!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72490544/how-to-build-dual-axes-barchart-via-ggplotly

Answer (score 1):

The order of `model` by `cost` can be done by setting the levels of the factor. Changing `geom_text` to `geom_label` created boxes instead of purely displaying the text. I am not sure what you mean with ". Specify the colour of every bars manually myself".  Do you mean the fill? The color is now determined by your factor and can be changed by `scale_fill_manual`, but you already do that.

```
#data
df <- data.frame (model  = c("A", "B", "C","D","E","F"),
                  share = c(12,20,15,9,60,20),
                  sale = c(16,25,18,14,67,28),
                  cost = c(14,19,28,24,57,28))

#set levels of model by cost
df$model <- factor(df$model, levels = arrange(df, desc(df$cost))$model)

#set to long format
df_long <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -model
  )

#plot (changed geom_text to geom_label)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = model, y= value, label=value))+
  geom_col(data = filter(df_long, name != "cost"), aes(fill=name), position = position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "grey"))+
  geom_line(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), aes(color = name, group = 1), size = 0.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = "red")+
  geom_point(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), size = 2)+
  geom_label(data = filter(df_long, name == "cost"), hjust=0, vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Sale and Share",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~., name ="Cost")
  )+
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: I need to specify colour of each bar individually